# Can I somehow include Maple procedure into C++ code

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, maple

I have a math problem, solved using Maple, but it must be solved in C++.
The problem is that I can't find a numerical method for one of the equations (it was solved with built-in maple "solve" procedure). Can I somehow include this procedure into my code or find somewhere that shows full descriptions of Maple's numerical methods. 
The equation is a system of complex algebraic equations.

Comment: how complex? if you can define your problem i'm sure plenty of people on this site can give you the numeric method

Comment: [Complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) or complicated?

Comment: Complex. And quite cpmplicated

Comment: z*sqrt(1+m^2)+ksi*sqrt(n^2+m^2)+i*m*x=t where m - unknown complex variable, z,n,x,t - real parameters, i - Imaginary 1

Answer (score 1):

You say you have solved the equation Maple, so I assume you do have the analytical solution. Why would you need then a numeric one? Generate the C code from the solution as documented [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=CodeGeneration%2FC), review it carefully and copy paste into you C++ program under development.

Comment: It is doubtful that the symbolic solution is helpful. The equation `z*sqrt(1+m^2)+k*s*i*sqrt(n^2+m^2)+i*m*x=t` can be transformed via squaring twice into a polynomial of degree 4, and while the Ferrari method exists, it is rather complex and hard to make robust. Using any polynomial root finder like Newton or Laguerre is probably more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

well I'm assuming at solve-time you have values for z,n,x,t, and that ksi thing in the second term. If so, I'd suggest using a quasi-Newton method, some of which are listed here

[Quasi-Newton Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method).

The resulting math can be coded in C++ of course, and i'm sure some implementations exist outside.

The reason why I make this suggestion is that your system (not really sure i see a system? just a nonlinear function) is nonlinear, and a Newton method would be useful only if you made good initial guesses. Most of these are guaranteed to converge, even if slowly, given any initial condition.

Unless you code it improperly haha

EDIT 2: NVM about EDIT 1. that is a doozy of a price tag lol

---

EDIT: You may be able to make use of this computing library which has C++ hooks (then again this sounds like an assignment, so maybe you can't):

[NAG Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAG_Numerical_Library)